# Update Model from connectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm editing a ASP.NET project. I had to do changes in the database, but the project doesn't have a Entity Data Model. How can I update the models?

It has the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectContext" connectionString="Server=sql-MYPROJECT-.amazonaws.com,3306;Database=dbname;User ID=user;Password=pass;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=20;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

The connection is working well. It has a folder Models->Tables. Inside this table folder has all the table models.

I changed some tables and create a new one. How can I update the model?

Thanks

Comment: You have an Edmx file in your project? If yes, open it on open space right click and say Update Model or Update XXXX, don't know the exact wording. If no, you just wasted your time since your project uses model first and you have to modify your models and update database based on that.

Comment: The project doesn't have this file. I believe that I should create the model first.